# create copy of custom object record salesforce

Tags: triggers, salesforce, clone, apex

I am trying to make a copy of record on a custom object (Work_order__c) when the record is created. I think this is close but I am not sure what I am missing.

THIS WORKS:

```apex
trigger CloneWorkorder on Work_Order__c (after insert) {

    List<Work_order__c> CaLNewList = new List <Work_Order__c>();

    for (Work_order__c WorkOrder : Trigger.new) {
        if (workorder.CreateCopy__c) {
            CaLNewList.add(new work_order__c(
                               case__c = workOrder.case__c));
        }
    }
    insert  CaLNewList;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need to change some information you can use this one

```apex
trigger CloneWorkorder on Work_Order__c (after insert) {

    List<Work_order__c> CaLNewList = new List()<Work_order__c>;

    for (Work_order__c WorkOrder : Trigger.new) {
        CaLNewList.add(new work_order__c(case__c = workOrder.case__c));
    }

    insert  CaLNewList;

}
```

OR if you need exactly same copy

```apex
trigger CloneWorkorder on Work_Order__c (after insert) {

    List<Work_order__c> CaLNewList = trigger.new.deepClone();
    insert  CaLNewList;

}
```

Comment: Im going with the one that lets me change some info. Also added an If statement. Im getting an error at line 2 (expecting a left angle bracket, found '(' )

Comment: 'code' trigger CloneWorkorder on Work_Order__c (after insert) {

    List<Work_order__c> CaLNewList = new List();

    for (Work_order__c WorkOrder : Trigger.new) {
        if(CreateCopy__c == TRUE){
        CaLNewList.add(new work_order__c(
        case__c = workOrder.case__c));
    }
}
    insert  CaLNewList;

}'code'

Comment: @Rich please see the changes in my answer. I've missed that list creation was wrong, also your if statement will not be working because  CreateCopy__c does not exist

Comment: I see that you've fixed it :)

Comment: I did! I wouldn't have been able to do it without your initial submission so I called gave it the answer! Thanks for your help.